# AWS owned CMKs vs AWS managed CMKs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

**Question # 0**: AWS console displays AWS managed keys and Customer Managed Keys; it doesn't display AWS owned CMKs as an item in the list. As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#master_keys), customers cannot view or manage AWS-owned CMKs. However, under  AWS managed keys, I see keys that were not created by me either implicitly or explicitly. Particularly I see this key with the alias `aws/dynamodb`. When I created DynamoDB tables, I used default settings which means, it will use AWS-owned CMKs for encryption at rest. Does this mean, "aws/dynamodb" is an AWS-owned CMK? It is a bit ambiguous. Is there a field in `aws kms describe-key` that displays the type?

[image: Console]

The default option in us-east-1 is AWS owned CMK

[image]

**Question # 1**: Other than rotation policy, ownership, and the cost, is there a fundamental difference in the way AWS-owned CMKs encrypt/decrypt data when compared to AWS-managed CMKs?

**Question # 2**: As per the documentation, AWS-owned CMK usage is not limited to one particular account, this means there is a possibility that AWS uses the same CMK across multiple different accounts  Is this understanding correct?

**Question # 3**: What services besides DynamoDB use AWS-owned CMKs for encryption at rest? In the picture, I see some more keys, and those are corresponding services that I tried.

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this mean, "aws/dynamodb" is an AWS-owned CMK?

No. AWS-owned CMKs don't show in your KMS console. The `aws/dynamodb` is AWS-managed CMK which is **not free**. It is the second option in DynamoDB table creation:

[image]

Q1. From the cryptographic point of view there is not difference, at least I'm not aware of any. But practical difference is that you can't use `AWS-owned CMKs` on your own. You **can't use it to decrypt/encrypt your own data** using AWS CLI or SDK, as the CMK is only used by AWS. The other difference is that it can be easier to move encrypted data between accounts, as AWS will use same AWS owned key on both accounts, rather then you managing different keys on different accounts.

Q2. Yes, that's correct. AWS can re-use the same key for multiple customers.

Q3. I think S3 is the most common service using AWS-owned key [SSE-S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingServerSideEncryption.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering. The default option in us-east-1 is AWS-owned CMK. I updated my question.

Comment: @bp4D In all regions is same. If you want to use AWS-managed CMK, you have to choose the second option.